# Check for multiple string within another multiple string in a list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to take a multiple string, and then find which blocks of that string are within a list. Most other answers for questions like this involve the use of `set()` or `any()`, which all take single string arguments.

So the code should look something like this:

```
my_list = ["spam", "eggs", "foobar and monty python"]
search_term = "monty python"
if search_term in my_list:
     return True
```

But this doesn't work, so how do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because `"monty python"` is not in `my_list`, but `"foobar and monty python"` is. If you want to find if any string in a list contains another string, you need to iterate over the list and use `in`:

```py
for i in my_list:
    if search_term in i:
        return True
```

When `i` represents that last element `"foobar and monty python"`, `search_term in i` will be `True` because `"monty python" in "foobar and monty python"` is `True`. To use `any()` as mentioned in you question for more concise code:

```py
any([search_term in i for i in my_list]`)
```